# Javascript replacing characters using replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this piece of code

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript String replace() Method</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
         var str = "zara ali";
         var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");

         document.write(newstr);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain please what is this and how it's read?

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
```

Also in `str.replace(re, "$2,$1);` , what is $2 & $1?

Comment: Look for tutorials on regular expressions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: What you're looking at in that variable re is a regular expression. A simple Google search should tell you a lot.

Comment: got it, they were special characters for regular expresions. thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the link in the comment I posted above to learn about regular expressions.
But to explain to you what the code you posted actually does...

`var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;` is a regular expression. the leading and trailing `/` are delimiters and don't actually have anything to do with the replacement going on other than telling the interpreter what the actual expression is: `(\w+)\s(\w+)`

- The `()` are called capturing parenthesis, and are remembered by the browser so that they can be used later in the replacement. The first set is assigned to $1, the second to $2, etc...
- `\w` matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. It's equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]
- `+` means apply the previous expression one or more times
- `\s` matches a single whitespace character

So your expression says look at the string `"zara ali"` for one or more alphanumeric characters (and remember them as a group, storing them in `$1`), then a white space character, then another group of one or more alphanumeric characters (and remember them as a group, storing them in `$2`). If a match is made, replace the string with the string `"$2, $1"`, which is really the second capturing group, followed by a comma and a space, ending with the first capturing group.

So you start with: `"zara ali"` and end with `"ali, zara"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");
```

replaces the second word with the first word and puts a `,` in between. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is a link to a regex "cheat-sheet." Regex is kind of confusing but it can be really great once you get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://regexr.com/3beap. That site is really helpful when dealing with Regular Expressions. If you hover over different parts of the expression (under the blue bar) it'll tell you what each part does. If you have over different parts of the substitution (bottom gray bar) it'll tell you what each part does.

There are also numerous Regular Expression tutorials that you can find with a Google Search that cover the basics.

But to put into simple English what your code does is:

- `\w+` matches one or more letter
- `\s` matches a single space
- `()` captures the match for reference later and saves them in $# where # is a digit `1-9` starting with 1 and increasing for each captured group in the order they are captured
- so `$1` is the first `()` and `$2` is the second `()`.
- in your example the `$1` is `zara` and `$2` is `ali`
- in the replace all you're doing is matching that regular expression, capturing the output to `$1` and `$2` and then replacing it with "$2, $1" which becomes "ali, zara".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The script is meant to transform a string in the form `"FirstName LastName"` into `"LastName, FirstName"`, using a regular expression. The line

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
```

creates the regular expression, and here's a breakdown of how it works, `#` denoting a comment:

```
/     # open regular expression
  (     # open a capturing group, aliased as $1
    \w    # match any alphanumeric character or underscore
    +     # match a single or multiple occurrences of the preceding token
  )     # close capturing group $1
  \s    # match a single space
  (     # open capturing group $2
    \w+   # match any single or multiple alphanumeric character or underscore
   )    # close capturing group $2
/     # close expression
```

The line

```
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");
```

applies the regular expression to `str`, extracting the capturing groups, reverses them, and adds a comma in between.